# What happens to TFS Build service when running in Interactive Mode?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I am trying to setup a build agent to build my Win8 app, which I'm told I should be able to do on a Server 2012 machine.

Everything was going well, until the step told me to stop the build service and run it in 'interactive mode'.

What this appears to do, it make the service run with a command prompt saying "I'm running in interactive mode, press escape when done" (When I pressed escape the build service stopped).

My question is this, if I need to run the build service in interactive mode for win8 builds, how will I cope for the inevitable situation when the server restarts, or some admin logs the user out? presumably the build service will stop.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

unless there is a specific reason why you need to run in interactive mode, i was building win8 apps all last year on a 2012 server running with out interactive mode and it ran fine. try it without and see what happens

Comment: I was at this point following a guide, there is no specific reason except that the guide said I'll hit the following error "Could not start the test run because Unit Tests for Windows Store apps cannot be run from a service or non-interactive process."
Can you confirm whether your apps have unit tests as part of the build process?
Mine won't build at the moment due to an issue including SQLite as part of the build, don't suppose you know a way to include that in your build?

Comment: sorry can't remember that far back and at a different client now, what is the SQLlite issue?

Comment: Well, the build agent can't resolve the reference to SQLite and since it's installed via the 'Extensions & Updates' menu in VS, rather than nuget or a manual .dll I'm not sure how best to pass the dependency to  TFS. I've asked it a separate question here if you have any input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647330/how-to-include-an-extension-or-update-as-a-dependency-in-a-tfs-build

Comment: Personally i always have visual studio installed on the build server, It is the only way to get code coverage results.

Comment: Interesting, do you not think that introduces a whole bunch of assemblies onto the build server which may not be present on the deployment environment? Worried we may end up assuming deployment would work, not picking it up until too late and needing VS on a production environment :/

Comment: I've never had an issue, it ensures all frameworks are available. not overly familiar with SQLLite, how would it be installed onto your target machines? is it a store package? having a very quick cursorary glance is it not just a case of setting the dll's to be copy always so they are part of the solution?

Comment: Yeah it comes as an Extension & Update in VS, which then adds a reference to the project. This is packaged up nicely when you ask the app to build the store appx packages but not when the build agent wants to run tests with the assembly :(

Comment: you could just replicate the file locations on the buuild server, i.e. just copy the folders from your dev box to the build server into the same location

Comment: Turns out that if you don't run TFS in interactive mode you get the following error: Could not start the test run because Unit tests for Windows Store apps cannot be run from a service or non interactive process. Please run unit tests from an interactive process. See [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254169]