# How to include an 'Extension or Update' as a dependency in a TFS build?

Tags: sqlite, tfs, msbuild

I have a project I wish to build via TFS2013 which is failing due to a dependency on SQLite on the build agent, specially:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1728): Could not find SDK "SQLite.WinRT, Version=3.8.4.3".
```

If this was a nuget package, fine, I could include the packages folder, use automated package restore etc, but in this case, the SQLite dependency is installed via the 'Extensions & Updates' section in Visual Studio.

My question is this, how can I provide such a dependency to TFS to allow it to find the reference?

Can I simply include the `vsix` file in a `dependencies` folder? Or do I really need to install VS and install the extension via that? I'd really hope to avoid the second option here.

Has anyone else hit this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think Install Visual Studio and Visual studio extension is what you need to do.

If you think about it, extensions form part of the development environment. You don't change your dev tools / development environments as part of your build process.

Comment: I guess so, I was thinking that it'd be quite easy for someone to develop locally, being dependent on a VS tool/component. See their tests pass on the build server and deploy, before picking up a dependency which may not exist on test, systest or production.

Comment: On closer inspection vs was already on the build server, so adding the extension worked fine